# New project FileNotFound

Tags: android

Just generated a fresh Android project and started constructing the layout.

This error has been bugging me ever since the beginning:

```
Error:java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\Restoration\Workshop\App\Test\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-ldrtl-xxhdpi-v17\abc_ic_menu_copy_mtrl_am_alpha.png (The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open)
```

I don't understand anything about it. It resolves itself sometimes when I do different combinations of Rebuild and Clean, but the next time it pops up it says it can't find a completely different resource in the same directory:

```
\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\
```

And all the files it claims not to find is there.

gradle file:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xx.xxx.android"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.0'
    compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:24.0.1"
    compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Would deeply appreciate if someone got any tips on fixing this, really annoying.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: provide your `gradle` file. it seems that you have problem with your back button styling ( if you are doing this )

Comment: @xAqweRx included the gradle file in my edit